# pausing and playing setInterval() on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am making a timer in javascript and am having some trouble starting and stoppimg the timer without the timer jumping ahead when it starts again. I've put in a boolean (isPaused) to pause and play setInterval, but when I play the timer jumps whatever length of time it has been paused. I tried recalling the setInterval function on play and I've tried resetting the variable that determines how long to count down (timeLeft). the timeLeft variable is the same when i pause it and play it so I'm not sure why it is jumping around like that.

my HTML :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <button id="start-button">Start Timer</button>
      <button id="pause-button">Pause Timer</button>
      <button id="play-button">Play Timer</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <span id="display-minutes"></span>
      <span id="display-seconds"></span>
      <span id="display-milli"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my JavaScript:

```
var minutes = 25;
var seconds = 0;
var milliseconds = 0;

var endTime = 0;
var timeLeft = 0;
var dateAtPause = 0;
var isPaused = false;

$('#display-minutes').html(minutes);
$('#display-seconds').html(seconds);
$('#display-milli').html(milliseconds);

//calculate time remaining between now and endTime
function timeRemaining() {
  timeLeft = Date.parse(endTime) - Date.parse(newDate());
  var milliseconds = Math.floor(timeLeft % 1000);
  var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft/1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor(timeLeft/1000/60);
  var total = timeLeft;
  return {
    'milliseconds': milliseconds, 
    'seconds': seconds, 
    'minutes': minutes,
    'total': total, 
  };
}

function updateClock() {
  if (!isPaused) {
    var time = timeRemaining();
    $('#display-minutes').html(time.minutes);
    $('#display-seconds').html(time.seconds);
    $('#display-milli').html(time.milliseconds);
    if (time.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeInterval);
    };
  };
};

$('#start-button').click(function() {
  //set time (var minutes) minutes from now
  var startTime = new Date();
  endTime = new Date(startTime.setMinutes(startTime.getMinutes() + minutes));

  updateClock();
  var timeInterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);

});

$('#pause-button').click(function() {
  isPaused = true;
  dateAtPause = new Date();
  console.log(timeLeft);
});

$('#play-button').click(function() {
  isPaused = false;
  var timeInterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
  console.log(timeLeft);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you chose to use a point in time for the endtime and lose track of the original duration needed.

Conceptually you will want to track the number of milliseconds left to run rather than an actual end time.

Functionality I would recommend:

```
timer = {};
timer.duration = 10000; //one field to track the expected duration (milliseconds is easiest to deal with)
timer.elapsedTime = 0; //another field to track what time has elapsed
```

And just keep track of the elapsed time vs the duration you expect it to run for.

I created a jsfiddle for you to see the functionality: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ct9Lohyr/6/)

Answer (score 1):

When you pause / play the previous timer is not cleared and the end time is not changed. That's why the remaining time continues to go down even during the pause.

After hitting play, you have one more timer, so you keep increasing the number of running timers.

Also, the `clearInterval` in `updateClock` does nothing to the `timeInterval` variables that are created locally in the other functions.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I needed to declare a global var for the setInterval so I could call the clearInterval from other functions, like you said I was just making new timers each time and not ending the others.